# How to remove wood framing from concrete floor

Tags: concrete, framing, framing-fasteners

I remodelling my cabin and removing a closet. The wood framing seems to be glued(?) to the concrete floor.

What's the proper way to remove the framing? Best idea I've got is a big crowbar but I wonder if I'll damage the concrete. Is there any magic fasteners I might be missing?

The concrete is, as far as I can tell, the last layer to the ground. Construction year is 1980-something, Quebec, Canada.

[image]

Comment: Use a piece of small wood under the ply bar for protection if worried.  If lucky by being careful, might even save some of the wood(don't count on it).

Comment: I'd be inclined to saw most of the way through the wood near the fasteners, to encourage the wood to split there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look closely, you'll see that about 10cm from the end of the board, there is an orange plastic thing that looks squished.  That is the plastic collar from a powder-fired nail.  Firing nails through sill plates is a common way to fasten wood to concrete.

You'll need to cut that nail and any others that might also be there.  I would suggest a reciprocating saw with a bi-metal blade.  You can squeeze the blade underneath the wood and slice that nail, along with any adhesive they might have used as well.

Comment: Good catch on that nail.

Comment: You can pull the wood up with a 36" prybar. The fasteners might come with it or pull through the wood and have to be pulled individually. Either way, expect a chunk of concrete to come up with the fastener,  leaving a divot in the floor. The answer by @Chris O eliminates the divots and leaves the floor smooth.

Comment: There appears to be another dirty circle (from the nose of the nail gun) about 10-12 cm from the wall, and possibly a 3rd even farther back, inside the left-right wall.